# JSON Body is Not Passing Certain Strings

Tags: javascript, json, string, spring-boot

```
function sendDataToServer(
  firstName,
  lastName,
  phoneNumber,
  address,
  birthday,
  age,
  idNumber,
  gender,
  degree,
  intake,
  semester,
  course
) {
  console.log("sending date" + birthday);
  console.log("sending nic" + idNumber);
  console.log("sending phone" + phoneNumber);
  console.log(typeof phoneNumber);
  console.log(typeof idNumber);
  console.log(typeof birthday);
  fetch("http://localhost:8080/student/add", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      address: address,
      birthday: birthday,
      age: age,
      idNumber: idNumber,
      gender: gender,
      degree: degree,
      intake: intake,
      semester: semester,
      course: course,
    }),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        alert("Student added successfully");
      } else {
        alert("An error occurred");
        console.log(response);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      alert("An error occurred");
    });
}
```

This function takes in various parameters representing user data such as firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, address, birthday, age, idNumber, gender, degree, intake, semester, and course.

These are all String data and in database also these are all defined as Strings

I take the date, nic and phoneNumber as Strings and tried to pass it, but JSON body does not passing these three Strings but it passing other strings.
Why is that ??

**Dummy data for post**

{
"firstName": "John",
"lastName": "Doe",
"phoneNumber": "1234567890",
"address": "123 Main Street",
"birthday": "1990-01-01",
"age": 31,
"idNumber": "123456789012",
"gender": "male",
"degree": "Bachelor of Science",
"intake": "2020",
"semester": "Spring",
"course": "Computer Science"
}

**Request Body**

{
"regNo": 28,
"firstName": "John",
"lastName": "Doe",
"phoneNo": null,
"address": "123 Main Street",
"nicNo": null,
"gender": "male",
"dob": null,
"age": "31",
"degree": "Bachelor of Science",
"intake": "2020",
"semester": "Spring",
"course": "Computer Science",
"enrollments": null
}

Comment: Can you add the raw request body from the network monitor? Checks like `idNumber !== "" && idNumber.length === 12` don't make sense. This check can be replaced with `idNumber.length === 12`. If the length is 12, it can't be an empty string. If age is greater than 18, it can't be an empty string.

Comment: Why is there a `phoneNo`, and not `phoneNumber` (to name just this difference, among others) in your request body? Is your function `sendDataToServer` the only one that's sending the data to your server?